# How to have inline functions in multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, linker, inline

My project has the following 4 files: `main.c`, `rcm.h`, `rcm.c` and `queue.c`.

In `rcm.h` I'm declaring all functions implemented in `rcm.c` and `queue.c`.

`rcm.c` looks like:

```
#include "rcm.h"

void rcm (void) {

  Queue *Q = init(10);

  /* Some other stuff */
}
```

queue.c` looks like:

```
#include "rcm.h"

extern inline Queue* init(int n) {
  return malloc(sizeof(Queue*);
}
```

and `rcm.h`:

```
#ifndef __RCM__
#define __RCM__

typedef struct queue { /*...*/ } Queue;

void rcm( void );

inline Queue* init( int n );
#endif
```

When compiling I get the the warnings

```
 gcc-7 -O0 -c rcm.c -o rcm.o
 In file included from rcm.c:15:0:
 rcm.h:58:15: warning: inline function 'init' declared but never defined
 inline Queue* init(int size);
               ^~~~
 gcc-7    -c queue.c -o queue.o
 gcc-7 main.c lib/rcm.o queue.o -o main
In file included from main.c:4:0:
inc/rcm.h:58:15: warning: inline function 'init' declared but never defined
 inline Queue* init(int size);
           ^~~~
```

But, when I am not declaring `init()` as `inline` compiles normally.

Comment: The question is: Why do you declare the _inline_ function `init()` in translation units, that do not define it? A function can only be inlined, if the definition is present in the source, it is not possible to inline it from other translation units.

Comment: Declare your inline functions (i.e. including the code) in the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

> `inline Queue* init( int n );`

In order for a compiler to be able to inline a function, it must know he code of a function.  Without that knowledge, the compiler *must* emit a call to that function<sup>1</sup>.  Hence the warning.  In order to use an inline function in several modules, you can define it in the header as:

```c
static inline Queue* init (int n)
{
    /* code here */
}
```

Cf. for example the [GCC documentation for `inline`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

The reason for the warning is that you want the function to be inline, but you are hiding the code from the compiler: `main.c` includes the header that declares an inline function but in that compilation unit, `init` is defined (implemented) nowhere.
<sup>1</sup> Except for functions built-in the compiler.  In that case, you don't have to provide the code yourself, it compiler has build-in knowledge about it.